# How do I replace underscores with spaces in autocomplete?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jquery-ui to create a search dropdown, but I'd like to replace underscores with spaces in the dropdown results.
I've tried .replace on the source but it doesn't seem to work.

Below is my autocomplete code. How do I use `.replace(/_/g, " ")` on it?

Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var alls = $.each([
    
    'Dr._Peppins',
    'Spain',
    'index',
    
    ],
    
    $( "#userInput" ).autocomplete({
    
    source: alls
    
    });
    
});
```

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: Your `$.each()` is malformed in this example.

Comment: Can you explain how so? Thank you

Comment: @Tecior I posted an answer that also includes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var alls = [
    'Dr._Peppins',
    'Spain',
    'index',
  ];

  function undScore2Space(word) {
    return word.replace("_", " ");
  }

  function filterArray(arr) {
    $.each(arr, function(i, e) {
      arr[i] = undScore2Space(e);
    });
    return arr;
  }

  $("#userInput").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(alls, req.term);
      resp(filterArray(results));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="userInput">Input: </label>
  <input id="userInput">
</div>
```

In your example, you perform an Each. This is not properly formed and should generate an error.

> In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array `index` and a corresponding array `value` each time. (The value can also be accessed through the `this` keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the `this` value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.) The method returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.

So you do not want to initialize Autocomplete on each item in the array. You can modify each part if you choose, yet if you expect the source to contain these characters, it would be best to filter them out after the lookup.

You can make use of a function for `source` and perform events this way.

You can also do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var alls = [];
    $.each([
      'Dr._Peppins',
      'Spain',
      'index'
    ], function(index, elem){
      alls.push(elem.replace("_", " "));
    });
    $("#userInput").autocomplete({
      source: alls
    });
});
```

Comment: That works well. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 source: alls.replace("_", " ");
```

Comment: I tried that, it seems to just break autocomplete altogether. Dropdowns disappear

Comment: How about removing the comma after 'index'?

Comment: Nope, removing the comma after the last string doesn't change anything.

Comment: `.replace()` works on a String not an Array of Strings. You must iterate each String element of the Array and perform replace on that. This is why this is not working.

Comment: Ok, this should fix it.  According to the documentation the source option can be a string so convert it:  alls.toString().replace()....